# 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Hey i have looked around through some simliar posts here on SO but havent found anything that has solved my problem. I have the following models,

```
from django.db import models

class Areas(models.Model):

    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    order_in_sidebar_network = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order_in_section_network = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.area_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Areas"
        verbose_name = "Area"

class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, help_text = "The name of the country")
    area = models.ForeignKey(Areas, verbose_name = 'Area')

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
        verbose_name = "Country"
        ordering = ['name']



class Offices(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, verbose_name = 'Country')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, help_text = "The name of this office, IE London")
    main_office = models.BooleanField(default= False, help_text = "Is this office a key location?", verbose_name = "Key Location")
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    address_3 = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional telephone contact number")
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional mobile contact number")
    fax = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null= True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional fax contact number")
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional additional data", verbose_name = "Additional information")
    data_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional additional data", verbose_name = "Additional information")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Offices"
        verbose_name = "Office"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class OfficeMembers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60, help_text = "Please tell us this person name")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, help_text = "The person's title, IE Managing Director")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional email address for this person")
    email2 = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, null = True, blank = True, help_text = "Optional second email address for this person")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank  = True, help_text = "Optional contact number for this person")
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 30, null = True, blank  = True, help_text = "Optional mobile contact number for this person")
    office = models.ForeignKey(Offices, null = True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Office Memebers"
        verbose_name = "Office memebr"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

i have the following view set up

```
def index(request):

    cache_key = "world_areas"
    cache_time = 60

    world_areas_cache = cache.get(cache_key)

    #if no cache is set, grab the objects, and set the cache

    logger.debug(world_areas)
    if not world_areas_cache:
        logger.info('No cache found grabbing objects')
        world_areas = Areas.objects.select_related().all()
        #cache.set(cache_key, world_areas, cache_time)
        logger.debug(world_areas)
    else:
        logger.info("Getting from cache")
        world_areas = world_areas_cache

    return render_to_response('network/index.html', {'world_areas':world_areas}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

trying to iterate over the world_areas object like so

```
{% for area in world_areas %}
```

produces a template syntax error

> 'RelatedManager' object is not iterable

Any one got any ideas why this is happeing? really cant seem to get round this! strangley this is working for me in shell :S am i missing something obvious???

Big thanks to anyone able to help!

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: So you're certain that it's not reading anything from the cache?

Comment: world_areas = Areas.objects.select_related().all()
return render_to_response('network/index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)) having only those two lines in the function returns same error!

Comment: ANyone! im about to  smash my computer up :D This works in shell i dont get it

Comment: Have a further look at your stack trace and your template code....?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920735/manyrelatedmanager-object-is-not-iterable

Answer (score 232):

[Call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls) `all()` to retrieve the elements from the manager.

```
{% for area in world_areas.all %}
```

Comment: because it was answered 2 years late.

Comment: @user1040495 that doesn't mean it's not the correct answer. the question author should be held accountable to accept this answer.

Comment: Why is there a difference between the `all()` and `all` call from the template?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen method calls from templates don't use parenthesis. Added link to docs.

Comment: @MarshallX because users may ask a question, wait a reasonable time and then not care anymore

Answer (score 15):

In general, it is better practice to use a `values` or `values_list` to pass data from a queryset to a template.

```
world_areas = Areas.objects.select_related().all().values_list('name', 'order_in_sidebar_network', ...)
```

Check out the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) for info on how to use the `values` function if you haven't used it before.

Answer (score 10):

I run into this issue by a reckless mistake:

```
 for physicalserver in task.physicalservers:
        physicalserver.relieve_task()
```

The `task.physicalservers` is `RelatedManager` object, in my case I should get the task's physicalservers, there should add `.all()`.

```
for physicalserver in task.physicalservers.all():
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You have to iterate over set to get values related to a fk in a model.

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    order_in_sidebar_network = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    order_in_section_network = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class CountryArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, verbose_name = 'Area')

 ## Assuming you have an object; area
 ## To get the all the counties related to that area you can do;
    {% for obj in area.countryarea_set.all %}
        <h4> {{ obj.name }} </h4>
    {% endfor %}
```