# ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable

Tags: django

Trying to do this:

```
wishList = WishList.objects.get(pk=20)
matches = [val for val in Store.attribute_answers.all() if val in wishList.attribute_answers]
```

And get this...

```
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Both fields are many-to-many so how can this be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704749/relatedmanager-object-is-not-iterable-django

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Try

```
matches = [val for val in Store.attribute_answers.all() if val in WishList.attribute_answers.all()]
```

Notice the parenthesis at the end of `WishList.attribute_answers.all()`. Adding the parenthesis invokes the `all` function to return an iterable.

If you include the parenthesis you're saying "give me all the values in the stores answers so long as that value is also in the wish lists answers". Without the parenthesis you're asking for all the values from the store's answers that are also in the `all` function, which is meaningless. The all function is not an iterable (it's a function that returns an iterable)

Answer (score 78):

Sounds like you are looking for something like

```
Store.attribute_answers.all()
```

Answer (score 61):

If you are doing this in a template:

```
{% for room in study.room_choice.all %}
  {{ room }}
  {% empty %}
  empty list!
{% endfor %}
```

UPDATE

If you have a through table, you can access the elements in that table (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358955/django-template-access-value-from-many-to-many-through-table/38359322)) like so (note, you use the through table name, in lowercase, suffixing _set):

```
{% for roominfo in participant.roomchoicethru_set.all %}
  {{ roominfo.room}} {{ roominfo.telnumber}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 48):

> > > **`all()`**

For everyone who finds reading code in questions as **TL;DR**

Instead of `query_set.many_to_many`

you should use
`query_set.many_to_many.all()`

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, can't get any simpler

Comment: And in a template it is `whatevertheobject.themanytomanyfield.all` without parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I keep hitting this question whenever this problem comes up. Particularly when trying to actually iterate over a manytomany in a function.

As a template you can do:

```
array = many_to_many.all()
for x in many_to_many:
  function here
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers are good and I just needed to add a point for easier understanding.You couldn't query the field where many to many is set because it returns and objects not a list of options.It is better to get the data from the field in your views then pass it to the templates.For example if you have posts model where each post has many to many relations with Tags model.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
      ""
class Post(models.Model):
      tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

If you tried post.tag.caption it will return this error.You should pass tags as a seperate idintifier in your views.

```
"post": identified_post,
"post_tags":identified_post.tags.all()
```

instead of passing only

```
"post": identified_post
```

Answer (score -2):

Here busines_type is foreign_key in profile model

```
pro = Profile.object.filter(user=myuser).first()
business_type = pro.business_type.all()
if business_type:
    b_type = ''
    for b in business_type:
        b_type += str(b.type)+' '
        a = b_type
```