# Django: template access value from many to many through table

Tags: django

I have the following table models.

```
class Experience(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    about = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Level(models.Model):
    level = models.IntegerField()
    details = models.TextField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    started = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    exp = models.ManyToManyField(Experience, through='ExperienceLinks')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Level %i" % self.level



class ExperienceLinks(models.Model):
    experience = models.ForeignKey(Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    modifier = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Passing in a level object to the template I'm trying to get the modifier for the experience for the level. I'm trying

```
  {% for exp in level.exp.all %}

      <p><span class="label label-secondary ">{{ exp }} (+{{ exp.modifier }})</span></p>

  {% endfor %}
```

I'm only getting the following for an output

```
exp1 (+)
exp2 (+)
```

So I can't access the modifier how i'd like to.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 11):

I think you want to call the `through object` in your template rather than the object that was passed into the M2M field.

```
  {% for exp in level.experiencelinks_set.all %}

  <p><span class="label label-secondary ">{{ exp }} (+{{ exp.modifier }})</span></p>

  {% endfor %}
```

Use `level.experiencelinks_set.all` not `level.exp.all`.

Comment: If this answer has helped you consider helping me by accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Works on Django 3.0.8. Should be chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: Sir, if I find you I WILL kiss you! I was going crazy with that issue and this solved it!