# Django reverse lookup of foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, reverse-foreign-key

I have a venue, this venue has many events happening there. My models look like this:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('published date',default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    venue_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    venue_country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.title)

class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField('published date',default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField('start date')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField('end date')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
```

I'd like to display all the events that are happening at a certain venue. How can I do that? My current view looks like:

```
def detail(request, venue_id):
    venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venue_id)
    return render(request, 'venue-detail.html', {'venue': venue})
```

Comment: What module do these fields relate too     description = models.TextField()?

Comment: Actually, these two models are each in their own app, I just posted them together to explain the point :)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can use `events = venue.event_set` to go the other way.

Note that `venue.event_set` is a manager object, like `Event.objects`, so you can call `.all`, `.filter`, `.exclude` and similar on it to get a queryset.

See the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: Great! THanks for that. However, If I want to iterate over the events (for i in events) I'm getting "'RelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: How did you change it to QueryObject  ?

Comment: @mp3por venue.event_set.all() or venue.event_set.filter(), usually.

Comment: If anyone stills sees the error `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar_set'`, you might want to check if `related_name` is set on the `ForeignKey`/`OneToOneField`/`ManyToManyField` of the child model (`Bar`) referencing the parent model (`Foo`).

Comment: Will this lookup be fast ? should he add foregin key to Venue ? will it make it faster ?

Comment: Note that if a "related_name" has been set on the foreign key def, you do not need to append "_set".

Comment: Be aware that setting `related_name="+"` on the `ForeignKey` will cause this to not be possible ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)).

Answer (score 10):

To those who have "'RelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Add all to retrieve the elements from the manager.

```
{% for area in world_areas.all %}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909142/2491526
(cannot add this in comment to the first answer)

Comment: You just saved my day [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65057186/13823230).

Comment: I was about to create mess in my models before I found this :D

Answer (score 7):

Go the other way round. Use `Event` model.

```
def detail(request, venue_id):
    venue = Event.objects.filter(venue__id=venue_id)
    return render(request, 'venue-detail.html', {'venue': venue})
```

PS: I have never used `get_object_or_404()`. Modify code accordingly.

Comment: So what can I use in my template to display the venue title and all the events happening at this venue?

Comment: in the template use {{ event.venue.title }} or as per your variables {{ venue.venue.title }} :) `{% for i in venue %} {{ i.venue.title }}`

Comment: I get that, but how do I display all the events happening at this venue?

Comment: the filter returns an array containing all the events that happen at the venue.loop over the array in the templates using the `for`

Comment: `venue = Event.objects.filter(venue__id=venue_id)` I think this expression will return QuerySet of Event object instead of Venue object.

Comment: @smilingwang read the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `venue.event_set.all()` to get all the events that are happening at a certain venue as shown below:

```py
def detail(request, venue_id):
    venue = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=venue_id)
    events = venue.event_set.all() # Here
    return render(request, 'venue-detail.html', {'events': events})
```