# Filtering by Foreign Key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

We extended Django's User Model with our CompanyRecord model. Every CompanyRecord is a User which all have a profile. When that user logins to system, we can pull it's data in it's CompanyRecord.

Our Campaign model is related to our CompanyRecord by a foreign key. Thus every CompanyRecord has a number of campaigns. I want to take those Campaigns which are related to the CompanyRecord. Basically, a CompanyRecord is a User. A CompanyRecord has many Campaigns. When a User which is also a CompanyRecord logins to system, I want to get it's associated Campaigns.
    In view, I want to take all the campaigns and filter them as, only the Campaigns which are related to our User would show up.

```
Necessary parts of our data model

    #models.py
    class CompanyRecord(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        company_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)



    class Campaign(models.Model):
        campaign_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        company_id = models.ForeignKey(CompanyRecord)
        category_id = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
        campaign_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


And the part of view.py

    @login_required
    def kampanyalar(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        company = request.user.get_profile
        userscampaign = Campaign.objects.filter( ###problem### )
        content = {'kampanyalar': kampanyalar, 'sirket':sirket}
        return render_to_response('kampanyalar.html', content, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the `Campaign`s for a `CompanyRecord` by reversing the relationship and using `company.campaign_set`:

```
company = request.user.get_profile()
userscampaign = company.campaign_set.all()
```

See also:

- [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)
- [Django reverse lookup of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to use your 2 line code, I get error :'function' object has no attribute 'campaign_set' 
My best guess is, this is because I get a User profile in company and try to use it's campaign_set but Python interpreter can't find because company is a "User" profile not a CompanyRecord. In this case I believe I have to try downcasting?

Comment: @MertÇelikok I think it's because you need to call `get_profile()` method. This `campaign_set` syntax would only work on `CompanyRecord` instance.

Comment: I believe `get_profile()` is deprecated. Try `company = request.user.companyrecord` instead to set `company` as the record rather than the user. `company.campaign_set.all()` should work then.