# Getting items in model referenced by a onetoonemodel in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have this database layout

```
class Clinic(models.Model):


class Menu(models.Model):
    ...
    menu = models.OneToOneField(Clinic, related_name='menu')


class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    menu = models.ForeignKey('Menu')
```

and I would like to access my Menu model and the Items linked to that menu from my Clinic model.

I have tried this

```
In [5]: clinic = Clinic.objects.get(pk=1)

    In [12]: clinic.menu
Out[12]: <Menu: Menu object>

In [13]: clinic.menu.objects.all()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2aff8882b6ad> in <module>()
----> 1 clinic.menu.objects.all()

/Users/gabriel/.virtualenvs/meed_waps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in __get__(self, instance, type)
    253     def __get__(self, instance, type=None):
    254         if instance is not None:
--> 255             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % type.__name__)
    256         return self.manager
    257 

AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Menu instances
```

but it tells me that the manager can't access it. Conceptually it seems like I should be able to access the items and get a list by tracing the relationship down through the clinic model like this Clinic > Menu > Items. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django reverse lookup of foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clinic.menu.objects` is the `ModelManager` for the `Menu` model - note that it's an attribute of the `Menu` *class*, not of your `clinic.menu` instance. `ModelManager` classes are used to query the underlying table, and are not supposed to be called directly from instances (which wouldn't make much sense anyway), hence the error message.

> Conceptually it seems like I should be able to access the items and get a list by tracing the relationship down through the clinic model like this Clinic > Menu > Items

That's indeed possible (hopefully), but where are you mentionning `items` in `clinic.menu.objects` ? You want `clinic.menu.item_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Clinic.objects.get(pk=1).menu.item_set.all()
```