# How to extend Django auth model User with UserProfile, avoiding RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-auth-models

I am trying to create UserProfile modal by extending default django User. Additional value cannot be saved because `User has no user profile:RelatedObjectDoesNotExist`:

```
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
    user.save()
    print(fb_id)
    user.userprofile.fb_id = fb_id
    user.userprofile.save()
```

modal :

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   fb_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
   follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)
```

Can't understand why it's wrong and how to do in the right way? Django 1.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django reverse lookup of foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys)

Comment: It doesn't exist because you didn't create one. Why is that confusing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `user.user_profile` until you have created it. You could do:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, fb_id=fb_id)
```

Comment: I've seen alot of bad answers all over the internet and this one, for me, actually answers the question and resolves the problem. I think the extending the user model needs to be a part of the django standard tutorial because it is allegedly so easy but I know I've sunk about 2 days into it, I have some working code, but I don't really understand what's going on.