# django shop subcategories implementation

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

I am building an ecommerce website using django 2.0.5 shop, I am stuck at implementing the subcategories for my products, I can't get an answer that is working on google and S.O

**my codes:**

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse 


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    #parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_list_by_category',
                       args=[self.slug])

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                          blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                      args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Product


@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug', 'price', 'stock',
                    'available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['available', 'created', 'updated']
    list_editable = ['price', 'stock', 'available']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm


def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    # subcategories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category__id=target_category.id)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    })


def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(
        Product,
        id=id,
        slug=slug,
        available=True
    )
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', {
        'product': product,
        'cart_product_form': cart_product_form
    })
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list,
         name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

html template for view:

```
<ul>
    <li {% if not category %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}">All</a>
    </li>
    {% for c in categories %}
    <li {% if category.slug== c.slug %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The categories and subcategories should be typed in the admin interface
i want it to produce a dropdown nest list under each category

e.g Electronics, Phones, Tablets

Answer (score 0):

You can access children categories from parent category. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys). And read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/topics/db/queries) carefully.