# How to find the children from a django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have two django models One for blog pages and one for the blog listing: a list of all blogs. The blogpage has a ForeignKey reference to the listing page.

```
class BlogListingPage(Page):
...
class BlogDetailPage(Page):

    blog_listing = models.ForeignKey(BlogListingPage,
                                     on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True,
                                     related_name='+',)
```

In views.py I have tried to look at the queryset object, but I cannot find a refernce to the detail pages.

```
def blog(request):
    context = {'data': BlogListingPage.objects.all()}
    query_set = context['data']
    for item in query_set:
        print(item.__dict__)
```

It does correctly tell me the number of detail pages in *numchild*

How can I access the children themselves?

[EDIT]
I have looked at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys) but it doesn't tell us how to generate *event_set*

```
{% for blog_listing in data %}
    <h2>{{ blog_listing.blog_listing_title }}</h2>
    {% for post in blog_listing.blogdetailpage %}
        <a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.blog_title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django reverse lookup of foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306897/django-reverse-lookup-of-foreign-keys)

Comment: You are using `'+'` as `related_name` which prevents Django to create a backwards relation. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: @HenryWoody That question does not tell us how to generate the event_set, so I am none the wiser

Comment: @Psionman `event_set` is the (default) related name for `Event` in relation to `Venue`, you've set the related name as `"+"` here, so you'll get a syntax error if you try the same here. Consider changing the related name (or leaving it out and going with the default), and that same syntax will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access related objects in [this way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager):

```
item.blogdetailpage_set.all()
```

Comment: where does blogdetailpage_set come from? "AttributeError: 'BlogListingPage' object has no attribute 'blogdetailpage_set'
"

Comment: @Psionman this should be a backwards relations from `BlogDetailPage` to `BlogListingPage` record, but I see you put `+` as `related_name` on FK in `BlogDetailPage` so this not gona work. Remove that attribute (or change it to a word-like) and create/run the migration - this will work then.

Comment: That works thanks. How do I access it in my template? {% for post in blog_listing.blogdetailpage_set.all %} doesn't seem to return anything?

Comment: You're welcome. `blog_listing` is a model instance or queryset? In second case you can't access related objects that way.

Comment: <class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager'. So what do I do?

Comment: so, it's a queryset (or then why you got `RelatedMager` after calling `all`). You could iterate through `blog_listing` objects and in nested loop iterate over related `blogdetailpage`. The right solution depends on what you want to achieve in result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206625/discussion-between-psionman-and-charnel).